# Include JAAS config file in Talend Job deployed

Tags: kerberos, talend

I'm using kerberos authentication in `tKafkaConnection` for my project. I'm aware of `Context Variables` for a Job so we can store the config file on certain path. 
Is there any way where we can include config file(s) in a Talend Job? What I have in mind is to create Context Variable path to the file like `./jaas.conf`.

N.B. I will deploy the job using TAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way to deploy a file (other than the job source files) within a job; as Talend doesn't provide a way to do this natively. You can either put it in a known location on your server, and use that path in a context variable, or modify the job zip after build and include your config file (if you are using prebuilt zip for deployment).